# Why am I not getting the right value?

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator

```
<html>
<head><title>One rep max</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculateOneRepMax(){
        var p = document.getElementById("button");

        p.onclick = showAlert;
    }
    function showAlert(){
        var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        var reps = document.getElementById("reps").value;
        var orm = ((weight * reps )/ 30) + weight;
        alert(orm);
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="calculateOneRepMax()">
<form>
  Weight: <input type="text" id="weight"/><br>
  Reps: <input type="text" id="reps" /><br>
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateOneRepMax()" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to create a calculator for one rep max in weightlifting using this formula. 
`(Weight *  Reps)/30 + Weight`.

The trouble is that the script is not adding the Weight after `(Weight * Reps)/30`. 
What's wrong here?

Comment: why do you have the event firing on the body onload? don't u only want it to calculate after clicking your button? onload will try to run with no values ... because there aren't any set in html at execution time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript when you add strings to a number, javascript doesn't perform arithmetic addition.  Instead it concatenates the two values together into a new string.

One way to fix your code is to use parseInt to make sure your weight and reps are numbers:

```
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value,10);
    var reps = parseInt(document.getElementById("reps").value,10);
```

There are other ways to do the same thing.

Edit:

There's another issue with your code.  calculateOneRepMax is unnecessary and doing it's job more often than it should.  You would be better off dropping it.  Removing the onload from body and changing the onclick on the button to showAlert():

```
<html>
<head><title>One rep max</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAlert(){
        var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        var reps = document.getElementById("reps").value;
        var orm = ((weight * reps )/ 30) + weight;
        alert(orm);
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form>
  Weight: <input type="text" id="weight"/><br>
  Reps: <input type="text" id="reps" /><br>
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="showAlert()" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```